# Why button border is not showing the color that I set to it?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I have set a border color to button border but button is not showing the color when I click it. It is showing another color. How can I fix it?

I want another help. How can I set button background like the below image? (I actually don't know what it is called)

The button I designed:

[image]

The button I want to design:

[image]

Also why the sub headline is not at one line? Why it is going to another new line?

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #926239;
    line-height: 1.6;
}
.first-div {
    background: url(./pexels-miguel-á-padriñán-1591060.jpg);
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-position:center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
.homepage-text {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.headline {
    color: #926239;
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 1.2;
}
.subheadline {
    color: #926239;
}
button {
    font-size: 18px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #926239;
    border: 1px solid #926239;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
button:hover {
    border: 1px solid #926239;
    background: #926239;
    color: white;
}
.second-div {
    color: white;
    background: #926239;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
.third-div {
    background: #f4f4f4;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
.section {
    display: flex;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    text-align: left;
}
.box-01, .box-03 {
    padding: 20px;
    color: white;
    background: #926239;
}
.box-02 {
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Project 07 (Landing page)</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="first-div">
            <div class="homepage-text">
                <h1 class="headline">Welcome To The Beach</h1>
                <p class="subheadline">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi officiis ipsum officia numquam expedita ullam.</p>
            <button>Read More</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="second-div"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit minus impedit maxime, quae soluta quis cumque perferendis! Doloribus quaerat, placeat iste facere, aspernatur ex cum veritatis laudantium, officia, non porro exercitationem incidunt quis dolore? Officia ex accusamus expedita optio, voluptatem minus? In maiores omnis aperiam earum ab molestiae beatae laborum blanditiis incidunt, delectus dolor, id voluptates optio aspernatur aliquam saepe atque labore? Tempore reprehenderit ab ipsam perspiciatis ut, provident perferendis sapiente in numquam blanditiis, enim, illo error nulla incidunt quos quidem ratione repellat ipsa molestias veritatis? Mollitia, fugit dolore commodi porro repudiandae atque, eos, ipsum quam culpa fuga deleniti quae.</p></div>
        <div class="third-div"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit minus impedit maxime, quae soluta quis cumque perferendis! Doloribus quaerat, placeat iste facere, aspernatur ex cum veritatis laudantium, officia, non porro exercitationem incidunt quis dolore? Officia ex accusamus expedita optio, voluptatem minus? In maiores omnis aperiam earum ab molestiae beatae laborum blanditiis incidunt, delectus dolor, id voluptates optio aspernatur aliquam saepe atque labore? Tempore reprehenderit ab ipsam perspiciatis ut, provident perferendis sapiente in numquam blanditiis, enim, illo error nulla incidunt quos quidem ratione repellat ipsa molestias veritatis? Mollitia, fugit dolore commodi porro repudiandae atque, eos, ipsum quam culpa fuga deleniti quae.</p></div>
        <section class="section">
            <div class="box-01">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa dolorum est, molestias dolores quis sunt nobis temporibus veritatis libero odio!</p>
            </div>
            <div class="box-02">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa dolorum est, molestias dolores quis sunt nobis temporibus veritatis libero odio!</p>
            </div>
            <div class="box-03">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa dolorum est, molestias dolores quis sunt nobis temporibus veritatis libero odio!</p>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it's because of outline.

Comment: Set outline: none; when active.

Comment: @George Thank you sir, the button problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for this.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #926239;
    line-height: 1.6;
}
.first-div {
    background: url(./pexels-miguel-á-padriñán-1591060.jpg);
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-position:center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
.homepage-text {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.headline {
    color: #926239;
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 1.2;
}
.subheadline {
    color: #926239;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
button {
    font-size: 18px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #926239;
    border: 1px solid #926239;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    outline: none;
}
button:hover {
    border: 1px solid #926239;
    background: #926239;
    color: white;
}
.second-div {
    color: white;
    background: #926239;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
.third-div {
    background: #f4f4f4;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
.section {
    display: flex;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    text-align: left;
}
.box-01, .box-03 {
    padding: 20px;
    color: white;
    background: #926239;
}
.box-02 {
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Project 07 (Landing page)</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="first-div">
            <div class="homepage-text">
                <h1 class="headline">Welcome To The Beach</h1>
                <p class="subheadline">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi officiis ipsum officia numquam expedita ullam.</p>
            <button>Read More</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="second-div"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit minus impedit maxime, quae soluta quis cumque perferendis! Doloribus quaerat, placeat iste facere, aspernatur ex cum veritatis laudantium, officia, non porro exercitationem incidunt quis dolore? Officia ex accusamus expedita optio, voluptatem minus? In maiores omnis aperiam earum ab molestiae beatae laborum blanditiis incidunt, delectus dolor, id voluptates optio aspernatur aliquam saepe atque labore? Tempore reprehenderit ab ipsam perspiciatis ut, provident perferendis sapiente in numquam blanditiis, enim, illo error nulla incidunt quos quidem ratione repellat ipsa molestias veritatis? Mollitia, fugit dolore commodi porro repudiandae atque, eos, ipsum quam culpa fuga deleniti quae.</p></div>
        <div class="third-div"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit minus impedit maxime, quae soluta quis cumque perferendis! Doloribus quaerat, placeat iste facere, aspernatur ex cum veritatis laudantium, officia, non porro exercitationem incidunt quis dolore? Officia ex accusamus expedita optio, voluptatem minus? In maiores omnis aperiam earum ab molestiae beatae laborum blanditiis incidunt, delectus dolor, id voluptates optio aspernatur aliquam saepe atque labore? Tempore reprehenderit ab ipsam perspiciatis ut, provident perferendis sapiente in numquam blanditiis, enim, illo error nulla incidunt quos quidem ratione repellat ipsa molestias veritatis? Mollitia, fugit dolore commodi porro repudiandae atque, eos, ipsum quam culpa fuga deleniti quae.</p></div>
        <section class="section">
            <div class="box-01">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa dolorum est, molestias dolores quis sunt nobis temporibus veritatis libero odio!</p>
            </div>
            <div class="box-02">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa dolorum est, molestias dolores quis sunt nobis temporibus veritatis libero odio!</p>
            </div>
            <div class="box-03">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa dolorum est, molestias dolores quis sunt nobis temporibus veritatis libero odio!</p>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you sir, the button problem solved. But I have something more asked in this question. Can you please help me with those problems?

Comment: I changed. please check it. I think you should change code "white-space: nowrap;" to "normal" in mobile using media query.

Comment: Thank you so much sir. Your answer helped me a lot and I learned new items from your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You must use `background:transparent` for this:

> "I want another help. How can I set button background like the below
> image? (I actually don't know what it is called)"

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #926239;
    line-height: 1.6;
}
.first-div {
    background: url(https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/abstract-blue-geometric-shapes-background_1035-17545.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg);
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-position:center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
.homepage-text {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.headline {
    color: #926239;
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 1.2;
}
.subheadline {
    color: #926239;
}
button {
    font-size: 18px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #926239;
    border: 1px solid #926239;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    outline:none;
    background:transparent;
}
button:hover {
    border: 1px solid #926239;
    background: #926239;
    color: white;
}
.second-div {
    color: white;
    background: #926239;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
.third-div {
    background: #f4f4f4;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
.section {
    display: flex;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    text-align: left;
}
.box-01, .box-03 {
    padding: 20px;
    color: white;
    background: #926239;
}
.box-02 {
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Project 07 (Landing page)</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="first-div">
            <div class="homepage-text">
                <h1 class="headline">Welcome To The Beach</h1>
                <p class="subheadline">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
            <button>Read More</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="second-div"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit minus impedit maxime, quae soluta quis cumque perferendis! Doloribus quaerat, placeat iste facere, aspernatur ex cum veritatis laudantium, officia, non porro exercitationem incidunt quis dolore? Officia ex accusamus expedita optio, voluptatem minus? In maiores omnis aperiam earum ab molestiae beatae laborum blanditiis incidunt, delectus dolor, id voluptates optio aspernatur aliquam saepe atque labore? Tempore reprehenderit</p></div>
        <div class="third-div"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit minus impedit maxime, quae soluta quis cumque perferendis! Doloribus quaerat, placeat iste facere, aspernatur ex cum veritatis laudantium, officia, non porro exercitationem incidunt quis dolore? Officia ex accusamus expedita optio, voluptatem minus? In maiores omnis aperiam earum ab molestiae beatae laborum blanditiis incidunt, delectus dolor, id voluptates optio aspernatur aliquam saepe atque labore? Tempore reprehenderit ab ipsam perspiciatis ut, provident perferendis sapiente in numquam blanditiis, enim, illo error nulla incidunt quos quidem ratione repellat ipsa molestias veritatis? Mollitia, fugit dolore commodi porro repudiandae atque, eos, ipsum quam culpa fuga deleniti quae.</p></div>
        <section class="section">
            <div class="box-01">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa dolorum est, molestias dolores quis sunt nobis temporibus veritatis libero odio!</p>
            </div>
            <div class="box-02">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa dolorum est, molestias dolores quis sunt nobis temporibus veritatis libero odio!</p>
            </div>
            <div class="box-03">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa dolorum est, molestias dolores quis sunt nobis temporibus veritatis libero odio!</p>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir.

Answer (score 0):

Changes:
**ADD**:

> background-color: transparent;

**IN** THE **BUTTON** IN CSS FILE

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #926239;
    line-height: 1.6;
}
.first-div {
    background: url(./pexels-miguel-á-padriñán-1591060.jpg);
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-position:center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
.homepage-text {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.headline {
    color: #926239;
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 1.2;
}
.subheadline {
    color: #926239;
}
button {
    font-size: 18px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #926239;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid #926239;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
button:hover {
    border: 1px solid #926239;
    background: #926239;
    color: white;
}
.second-div {
    color: white;
    background: #926239;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
.third-div {
    background: #f4f4f4;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
.section {
    display: flex;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    text-align: left;
}
.box-01, .box-03 {
    padding: 20px;
    color: white;
    background: #926239;
}
.box-02 {
    padding: 20px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Project 07 (Landing page)</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="first-div">
            <div class="homepage-text">
                <h1 class="headline">Welcome To The Beach</h1>
                <p class="subheadline">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi officiis ipsum officia numquam expedita ullam.</p>
            <button>Read More</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="second-div"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit minus impedit maxime, quae soluta quis cumque perferendis! Doloribus quaerat, placeat iste facere, aspernatur ex cum veritatis laudantium, officia, non porro exercitationem incidunt quis dolore? Officia ex accusamus expedita optio, voluptatem minus? In maiores omnis aperiam earum ab molestiae beatae laborum blanditiis incidunt, delectus dolor, id voluptates optio aspernatur aliquam saepe atque labore? Tempore reprehenderit ab ipsam perspiciatis ut, provident perferendis sapiente in numquam blanditiis, enim, illo error nulla incidunt quos quidem ratione repellat ipsa molestias veritatis? Mollitia, fugit dolore commodi porro repudiandae atque, eos, ipsum quam culpa fuga deleniti quae.</p></div>
        <div class="third-div"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit minus impedit maxime, quae soluta quis cumque perferendis! Doloribus quaerat, placeat iste facere, aspernatur ex cum veritatis laudantium, officia, non porro exercitationem incidunt quis dolore? Officia ex accusamus expedita optio, voluptatem minus? In maiores omnis aperiam earum ab molestiae beatae laborum blanditiis incidunt, delectus dolor, id voluptates optio aspernatur aliquam saepe atque labore? Tempore reprehenderit ab ipsam perspiciatis ut, provident perferendis sapiente in numquam blanditiis, enim, illo error nulla incidunt quos quidem ratione repellat ipsa molestias veritatis? Mollitia, fugit dolore commodi porro repudiandae atque, eos, ipsum quam culpa fuga deleniti quae.</p></div>
        <section class="section">
            <div class="box-01">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa dolorum est, molestias dolores quis sunt nobis temporibus veritatis libero odio!</p>
            </div>
            <div class="box-02">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa dolorum est, molestias dolores quis sunt nobis temporibus veritatis libero odio!</p>
            </div>
            <div class="box-03">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa dolorum est, molestias dolores quis sunt nobis temporibus veritatis libero odio!</p>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```